# Cookie set-up stopping back-end login after server migration in Magento

Tags: php, validation, magento, session, cookies

I am in the process of moving my development site into production and have moved the site over on AWS. All seems fine but the only problem that occurs is that I cannot login to the back-end of Magento due to some sort of cookie related problem.

Here is the cookie set-up as of right now:

**Session Cookie Management**

Cookie Lifetime: 86400

Cookie Path: /

Cookie Domain: .mydomain.com

Use HTTP Only: Yes

Cookie Restriction Mode: No

**Session Validation Settings**

Validate REMOTE_ADDR: No

Validate HTTP_VIA: No

Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: No

Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT: No

Use SID on Frontend: No

I noticed the other day that cookies were expiring in the past so I started looking into possible solutions and this is the only thing at the moment that allows me to login:

Changing the following lines in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

FROM:

```
// session cookie params
$cookieParams = array(
    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
    'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
    'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

TO:

```
    // session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
     //   'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    //   'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
   //    'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
```

Now obviously this is just a temp work around so I can login, I don't really want to open up any security flaws or change any of Magento's core files.

Bit more information about the site set-up. It is a Magento 1.8.1 Community edition site running on an m1.medium instance on EC2.

So, my question is, does anybody know how to fix this the right way without potential problems in the future?

All help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we assume that you have used your browser to delete all of your local cookies? You should visit the login page without any previously set cookies active.

You could also:
a) Delete everything in `var/cache/`
b) Check that the configuration value admin->system->configuration->web->Session Cookie Management is blank or is updated to your new base URL. Oh, you can't log in. Well, if you know you didn't ever set it then the default is blank so you should be okay. If you look at the page source in your browser for Mage.Cookie you should see what the domain is being set to. If it is wrong I think it can be set in `local.xml` but I'm not sure how to do that. I can tell you the path is `XML_PATH_COOKIE_DOMAIN    = 'web/cookie/cookie_domain'`

But I reckon clearing `var/cache/` and emptying your browser of all cookies for the domain should do the trick though.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I'm not sure which part fixed it to be honest but I cleared the field you mentioned, emptied /var/cache & /var/session (again), deleted all cookies and back reverted the Varien.php file back and it all works. Thanks for the help! :)